# Count lines of code in all java classes in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is there any way I can view the total lines of code in each java class in my project?

Looking for something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/136379) for Android Studio.

Answer (score 293):

**Go to**
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/4509-statistic
and install the latest version

**To install**

1. Run Android Studio
2. From the menu bar, select File-->Settings
3. Under IDE Settings, click Plugins, and then click Install plugin from disk
4. Navigate to the folder where you downloaded the plugin and double-click it
5. Restart Android Studio

**To count the lines**

1. Check the statistics option that is visible after installing the
   plugin
2. This option is near the run, debug, gradle console, bottom left corner of Android studio

**21/05/2015**

If you cannot see the *Statistics* options, do the following:

1. Select VIEW from the toolbar.
2. Select TOOLS Windows.
3. Choose STATISTICS.

You will see the statistics of your project and at the bottom, there is TOTAL section which displays the total lines under the Column of LINES.

Comment: Well, that's rather singular, in that you linked to exactly the same plugin as the existing answer, which would normally be rather useless… but then you gave rather detailed instructions for installation and use, so this is arguably better.

Comment: Good instructions. Files->Settings->plugins in windows. Note, does not actually work in windows. Click on "Refresh" but no statistics ever show up. Its very clear Android Studio and the tools which work with it were not made for Windows. For legal reasons, we are required to use Windows for this project. Ugh! (Well, its possible it would work but AS gets NPE's continually when run on Windows.)

Comment: You are right, I dont know if these instructions work with windows. It would be different for windows, Thank you

Comment: Works with Windows now. Nice.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1 and had to use version 2.3 release of the Statistics plugin. The newest versions of Statistics failed to load (2.4 and 2.5). I'm on OSX 10.10.

Comment: "Plugins" is located in File --> Settings in the newest version of Android Studio for Windows. I couldn't find it for a while because I was looking for a top-level menu bar entitled "Android Studio", which obviously doesn't exist. Can you update this to reflect that?

Comment: Its include R.java and other library file also not up to mark

Comment: This crashed my Android Studio 1.5.1.

Comment: The plugin can be also downloaded from repositories thru the File->Settings->Plugins option.

Comment: Following up on @Lavekush's comment: The plugin has settings to exclude compiler output directories, as well as other preset and custom directories (and file extensions). However I'm still getting plenty of R.java from the `build/generated` folder, so apparently that's not considered a compiler output directory. When I tried to add the `build` directory for exclusion and refresh, the plugin threw an exception.

Comment: I tried it now with Android Studio 4 and it's only counting the files in the root but not in the submodules/subdirectories :/

Answer (score 21):

You could try this plugin (It is for IntelliJ but should work with AS): http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4509

Comment: It does work with AS, and quite nicely.  Just installed for my own project.

Comment: Works for me! Android Studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 8):

Goto the link https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic and install it.

## **General Usage Instructions**

1. Install plugin from official Jetbrains plugin site,
2. After installing, just click on the TAB "Statistic" at the bottom of the screen (left side),
3. Click "Refresh" button to run statistic for whole project,
4. Click "Refresh on selection" button to run statistic for selected directory,
5. Click "Settings" button to customize plugin behavior,

   - Adjust "Excluded file types" with all extensions which you want to remove from the statistic (e.g. class;jar;...),
   - Adjust "Seperate TABs file types" with all extensions which you want to have in separate tab (e.g. php;java;...),

## **Note:**

1. Size - total size of the file,
2. Size Min - size of the smallest file of the given type,
3. Size Max - size of the biggest file of the given type,
4. Size Avg - average size of the file of the given type.

Answer (score 3):

Jetbrain's statistics plugin is counting only .java files. It is not accurate for getting android app source line of code.

We can use locmatrics for this.

http://www.locmetrics.com/

This will return loc for all the entered extensions.

Please set a valid output directory while checking this. Otherwise garbage files will be generated inside source directory

Comment: Update 2021: Url is down

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of lines of code in your entire project just write the below line in the terminal of android studio.

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l
```