# How to get number of lines of a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to get the number of lines written in a project in Android Studio (current version is 2.1.1) ? (without using a plugin would be better)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count lines of code in all java classes in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510185/count-lines-of-code-in-all-java-classes-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One way is to search `(ctrl+shift+F)` for line breaks `\n` with regular expressions enabled and `whole project` as the scope. If you want to limit the search to only java and xml files, you can use the following file mask `*.java, *.xml`

Comment: Simple and elegant. One thing to make sure is to scope the search so that it won't look through the automatically generated code (eg. R class).

Comment: If you mask *.java, Android studio differentiates source files and generated files and gives line count of each. R.class is part of generated files and its lines are not included in source files count

Comment: it's not working, display "100+ lines" instead of the real number

Comment: @Boukharist Click on 'Open in Find Window' which shows you the exact count

Comment: Type this as your regex expression [\n]+

Comment: In case it says `Nothing found`, make sure to enable Regex (The button with the `.*` sign)

Answer (score 31):

As alternative you can use (Linux, Windows) utility cloc (Count Lines Of Code). Cloc counts, and computes differences of, comment lines, blank lines, and physical lines of source code.

An example basic use (my project):

```
cloc /home/myHome/StudioProjects/myApp/app/src/
     111 text files.
     111 unique files.
       0 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.70  T=0.36 s (308.1 files/s, 38552.3 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Java                            50           1323            146           6407
XML                             60            460             50           3203
SQL                              1              0              0           2302
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           111           1783            196          11912
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Project page https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc (thanks Xam)

Comment: The project moved to GitHub: https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc

Answer (score 19):

You can use a addon/plugin for android studio

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4509

In Android Studio:

> From the menu bar, select Android Studio > Settings > Plugins > select the Marketplace tab > search for statistic > press install > restart the IDE.

Check the **Statistic** tab that is visible after installing the plugin.
This option is near the run, debug, gradle console, bottom left corner of Android Studio.

Comment: The settings for this plugin purport to allow you to exclude certain folders, but when I tried doing this, it still counted R.java and other files from the build folder.

Comment: It counts all lines by file type and aggregates them in a table. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: There is a issue . It count R.java files too . Any suggestions ??

Comment: The latest version shouldn't, I can see a setting "Exclude Android (R.java)"

Comment: Statistic option not visible on Android studio 3.5.1? Anyone else facing this issue ?

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative you can open a `Terminal` tab if you are using Linux|Mac OS and type

```
find . -type f|egrep ".xml|.kt|.java"|xargs cat|wc -l
```

In the folder you selected. You can change filters on egrep command as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Android cannot show your Lines of Code(LOC), but there is a plugin called **statistics** that can.

Install it in Android Studio, restart Studio and you'll see a "statistics" tab at the bottom. Press Refresh and xou gon get a bunch of statistics concerning your LOC.

Via the Settings, you can exclude directorys. Your /build and /app/build (in projectfolder) might be an option, since they contain auto-generated files