# Counting lines of java code and xml and finding response time in Android studio

Tags: android, performance, unit-testing, android-studio, testing

I want to count the lines of my java and xml code in android studio since i am using macbook and I installed statistics to android studio but it isn't showing statistics option in View->Tools window. I am unable to find statistics so how can I count my lines of code and also response time when i click on a button or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29909326/1982579

Please check this link it will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count lines of code in all java classes in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510185/count-lines-of-code-in-all-java-classes-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

for code lines count see :

[Count lines of code in all java classes in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510185/count-lines-of-code-in-all-java-classes-in-android-studio)

for the time you can caclulate it by code :

```
long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
///your desired code snippet
long endMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
System.out.println("elapsed time is: "+ endMilis-startMilis);
```

Comment: In this link they say to use statistics i already used it but it isn't showing up in android studio i restarted it but isn't helping

Comment: i am using the tool. reinstall the tool and relunch the android studio again

Comment: I've done it but still not appearing in macbook android studio